# Adaptive computation in neural ODEs

Tags: ode, neural-network

I have been reading the [neural ODE paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/file/69386f6bb1dfed68692a24c8686939b9-Paper.pdf) and I understand that neural ODEs have a continuous depth model structure. And I understand the fact that they are especially very useful for time-series data.
But from the benefits of neural ODEs stated in the paper, I can't understand what they mean by adaptive computation. Can anyone please explain to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neural networks generally have a fixed amount of computation which is generally referred to as the number of layers. A recurrent neural network applies some neural network `NN(x)` `n` times, and so it's `n` layers. But how many layers does a neural ODE has? That depends, since the number of `f` calls that an ODE solver does to solve `u' = f(u)` is dependent on many factors. Therefore, the number of layers in a neural ODE is the number of steps an adaptive ODE solver decides to take. This means that the neural ODE can effectively adapt the number of layers on the fly for different datasets, or take more steps or "harder" points and less steps for "easier" points.

This "implicitness" to the choice of layers then leads to some other questions. Can you build neural network architectures that automatically have some way of choosing the least number of layers (i.e. the fastest computation) for a given problem or for given inputs? It turns out that you can [by regularizing based on the adaptivity factors of the ODE solver](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/pal21a). Note that the paper also describes how adaptivity in ODE solvers works in some detail (in order to describe how to force neural ODEs to choose to the least steps).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on neural networks, so don't take what I say here uncritically.

My impression from skimming the paper is that they're replacing a set of discrete layers with a continuous pseudo-time domain, and replacing a recurrence relation between discrete layers with an ODE.
Now, there's no way to faithfully represent an arbitrary differentiable function with perfect accuracy, so at some point you still have to discretize that ODE by sampling at a finite set of "time" points $\{t_0, \ldots, t_N\}$.
At that point you've gone back from continuous time to a discrete set of layers, which begs the question of whether you gain anything at all by this ODE formulation.

The answer is that you might, in principle, gain something through this continuous viewpoint because there's a very rich theory of *adaptivity* for ODE discretizations.
Say that our ODE is

$$\dot z = f(z).$$

If we use some time discretization scheme, we don't know ahead of time what's a good timestep to use.
Adaptive schemes find ways to estimate the error and adapt the timestep on the fly.
I'll describe it briefly below assuming you've never seen this before, since it isn't explained in the paper itself.
But this is a pretty big subject and if you want to learn more, you should just read the [book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1) by Hairer and others.

The big idea behind adaptivity is to use two different time discretizations of the ODE and compare the results at each step.
For example, consider both a forward Euler scheme

$$z_{n + 1} = z_n + \delta t_n\cdot f(z_n)$$

and RK2:

$$\begin{align}
z_* & = z_n + \frac{\delta t_n}{2}\cdot f(z_n) \\
z_{n + 1} & = z_n + \delta t_n\cdot f(z_*)
\end{align}$$

The forward Euler discretization has an asymptotic accuracy of $\mathscr{O}(\delta t)$ while the RK2 method is $\mathscr{O}(\delta t^2)$.
The discrepancy between the forward Euler update and the RK2 update at any step gives an estimate of the error that can then be used to adjust the timestep $\delta t_n$.
You can play this game with essentially any pair of methods of different order, but it's especially advantageous to use Runge-Kutta methods where the lower-order scheme's stages are a subset of the higher-order scheme's; these are called embedded methods.
For example, the solver methods shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) include RK23 and RK45.

The nice part about all of this is that there's some good theory for how well adaptive ODE solvers work.
My understanding (and again, not a neural network expert) is that tuning the connectivity of a NN is more art than science.
Reframing the problem as an ODE and using all this theory about adaptive timestepping might offer a way to do away with some of the manual tweaking of the NN.